# Change start up project in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, source-control-explorer

I have 2 project in my solution explorer that one of this related to windows and other related to web,now i want to run web project but it runs in windows form so i want to know how to change the control to run the web project?

Answer (score 2):

you need to make the web project the start up project. Right click on the web project and choose the `Set As StartUp Project`.